# I weigh myself on scale at sea level, a weigh myself at 20,000 feet above sea level. Do I weigh the same, based on gravitational pull?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, weight

If I  knew this,  I wouldn't ask question,  because I would have enougb factors in the equation, to solve. If I was a physicists.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the *mass* $m$ of an object is invariant to its  w.r.t. its position relative to Earth.

But *weight* $W$, the attractive force exerted on the object by Earth, is not:

$$W(h)=\frac{GM_e}{(R_e+h)^2}m$$

is the force exerted by Earth on the object, $h$ $\text{meter}$ above the Earth's surface.

For $h=0$ we get:
$$W(0)=\frac{GM_e}{R_e^2}m$$

Clearly for $h > 0$, then $W(h) < W(0)$.

Comment: At that elevation (ignoring rotation), weight is reduced by ~0.2%, according to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%281%2B%2820000+ft%29+%2F+%28radius+of+earth%29%29%5E-2)

Answer (score 0):

No. You are further away from Earth, so the gravitational pull is less. While your mass is the same, the weight force you feel depends on where you are.